# why some Icons from Fontawesome are not working?

Tags: html, css, icons

I've set up my kit correctly on my index.html

```
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a*******5.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Some icons are working, others not.

```
<i class=" fa fa-search"></i> --------------> WORKS!

<i class="fa-solid fa-square-envelope"></i> --------> NOT WORKING!
```

It only shows a square, I've tried resseting css styles, changing colors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FA **version 5** or lower, the envelope icon name is `fa-envelope-square`. It changed to *fa-square-envelope* in version 6.

[Source](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/upgrade/whats-changed#icons-renamed-in-version-6)

Answer (score 0):

You need use a class in your icon. like this code below

Css:

```
        .my-icon {
            font-size: 48px;
            color: #FF0000;
            height: auto;
            width: auto;
        }
```

HTML:

```
    <i class="fa-envelope-square my-icon"></i>
```